# TensorFlow Keras issues

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to learn the very basics of Keras and how to use it and I'm running into trouble getting my model to work. I am following a tutorial online (https://youtu.be/qFJeN9V1ZsI?t=1696) word for word and getting errors when using the model.fit() function this is the second tutorial I have tried and gotten the same result.

I have looked at Keras's website and read all of the variable descriptions for the functions/followed instructions on site, and cannot work around the issue.

I am running this in a virtual environment with TensorFlow 2.0.0 and Keras 2.3.1

It may be worth noting that I am on an M1 MacBook Pro (not sure if that's the issue).

This is my first experience with Python and machine learning.

Code:[CodeImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKmH6.png)

```
model.fit(
x=scaled_train_samples,
y=train_labels,
batch_size=10,
epochs=30,
verbose=2,
callbacks=None,
validation_split=0.0,
validation_data=None,
shuffle=True,
class_weight=None,
sample_weight=None,
initial_epoch=0,
steps_per_epoch=None,
validation_steps=None,
validation_freq=1,
max_queue_size=10,
workers=1,
use_multiprocessing=False)
```

Issue:[ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuKgn.png)

Comment: You should start by not including code/messages as images, only as text.

Comment: First time poster, sorry. Will try to fix.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.